# Как объяснить обособление сравнительного оборота?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

"И при этом им даже не приходит в голову одеться,  как маглы" (Д. Роллинг).

В разных изданиях этой книги (в переводе И. Оранского) сравнительный оборот обычно обособляется, но встречаются варианты без обособления.

А как правильно и почему?

Кажется, что запятая не нужна, вот похожее предложение: Был мрачен, оделся как работяга ― в грязный ватник, в сапоги. [Ю. В. Трифонов. Время и место (1980)]

Возможное объяснение запятой:

И при этом им даже не приходит в голову одеться (так),  как (одеваются) маглы.

Это неполная (разговорная) конструкция, но тогда при чтении там делается два ударения: одЕться, как мАглы.

Answer (score 1):

Обособление меняет смысл предложения. "Не приходит в голову одеться, как маглы" значит, что не приходит в голову одеться вообще. То есть ходят голыми и не задумываются. После запятой мысль закончена. Сравнение получается кривым, не согласованным. "Не приходит в голову одеться как маглы" значит, что как-то всё-таки одеваются (как минимум, задумываются одеться), но не как маглы, а по-другому. Это цельная мысль, тут не нужна запятая.

**Дополнение:**

> Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства
>   образа действия, например: Тропинка извивалась как змея. В таких
>   случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или
>   существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ). К сожалению, не всегда
>   обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной уверенностью отличить от
>   обстоятельств сравнения.

[Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

Это Ваш случай. Приведённое предложение не исчерпывается тем, что героям не приходит в голову *одеться*. Им не приходит в голову ОДЕТЬСЯ КАК МАГЛЫ (КАК МАГЛАМ/ПОД МАГЛОВ/В МАГЛОВ/МАГЛАМИ). Где тут сравнительный оборот? Нет его. Это цельная фраза.

**И ещё**,  на счёт Вашей попытки объяснить неправильную запятую:

Здесь нечего разделять запятой. Сравните:

- «он крикнул, как (кричит) орёл
- «им не приходит в голову одеться как (одеваются) маглы»

При сравнительном предложении у нас опущено второе сказуемое, выраженное глаголом, а нашем случае есть инфинитив (одеться) — компонент составного глагольного сказуемого «хотели одеться». К сказуемому без запятой прибавляется обстоятельство образа действия ({одеться} как маглы).
При этом Вы вольны записать образ действия прямо, как в примере, либо заменить его **эквивалентом «так»**. В этом случае *запятая ставится по правилам написания оборота, но в самом образе действия её по-прежнему нет*: «хотели одеться так» = «хотели одеться по-магловски» = «хотели одеться как маглы».

Comment: Эта книга - очень известная детская фантастика о юном волшебнике Гарри Поттере (Она издается огромными тиражами, сейчас отмечают ее 20-летний юбилей). "Они" - это маги, которые носят зеленые мантии, то есть одеты особенным образом. И чтобы не выделяться среди окружающих, они должны были одеться так, как одеваются маглы (обычные люди). Из этого можно сделать вывод, что запятая не нужна, но она стоит в большинстве изданий. Может быть, здесь есть какая-то другая причина для ее постановки?

Comment: Я Вам уже ответил, тираж на пунктуацию не влияет. Ставите запятую, и меняется смысл так, как я написал.

Comment: Извините,  я просто думала, что можно задать еще один вопрос (о другой причине). Я думаю, что не во всех случаях запятые ставятся по стандартным   правилам, а эту книгу, вероятно, редактировали внимательно.

Comment: Современный книжный рынок  в России сплош состоит из ошибок. Возьмите другую детскую серию, "Коты-воители". Там ошибка на ошибке, хотя издательство "Просвещение". Причина для запятой не может быть другой. Вы либо пишете, что "они одеты", и это конец Вашей мысли, а потом сравниваете: одеты, как, например, одет кто-то ещё, допустим, маглы. Это развернутое написание конструкции с запятой. Либо говорите "одеты как маглы", то есть смысл фразы не в "одеться", а в том, чтобы одеться конкретным образом. Запятая меняет смысл фразы.

Comment: Спасибо, это я поняла. Меня как раз интересовал вопрос, нет ли особых причин для запятой.

Comment: Я  бы тоже не поставила здесь запятую, но почему-то она там стоит.  Я сомневаюсь, что это ошибка, а не авторский вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Оделся как работяга ~ оделся работягой. По крайней мере, можно так трактовать и запятую не ставить. Хотя я бы и здесь этот оборот обособил. А в случае с маглами - обычный сравнительный оборот, запятая нужна.

Comment: Одеться работягой — прикинуться работягой. Не так ли? Одеться как работяга — одеться, напр., несоответственно дресс-коду события.

Comment: Так. Но к тому примеру не имеет отношения. Точно ли он там "прикинулся работягой"? По мне так лучше не умствовать, а считать обычным сравнительным оборотом.